# Angular, receiving data but getting CORS

Tags: angular, cors

So I keep getting this error:

[image]

In my other Angular projects I send a preflight request to the server called OPTIONS before any POST or GET request, I noticed it is missing in this case and the server is responding correctly to the request but I cannot access it since the error is thrown and I have no access to the data.

My service has the next implementation:

```
  login(user) {
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
const body = new URLSearchParams();
body.set('grant_type', 'password');
body.set('username', user.username);
body.set('password', user.password);
return this._http.post('http://thevotechain.azurewebsites.net/Token', body, { headers: headers })
  .map((response: Response) => {
    return response.json();
  });
```

}

Help.

Comment: What do you use for your backend API. Which language, server?

Comment: @AshishRanjan we are using ASP .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your API set the response header with key:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

to `localhost:4200` for example.

When you set it to `localhost:4200`, you say that this frontend application can access me.

You can also set it to `*`, this will let any front-end application to use your API.

Comment: But shouldn't there be an OPTIONS request to the API?

Comment: @RichyST: You don't send an options request, your browser does. Please see this link too see check what are the type of requsts for which Options request will be sent by the browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS